# Password verification failed when setting up VPN tunnel

Tags: 22.04, password, vpn, openvpn, certificates

I'm trying to follow instructions in the "[Setting Up the VPN Tunnel](https://upb-pc2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PC2DOK/pages/1903406/VPN#Setting-Up-the-VPN-Tunnel)" section of [this webpage](https://upb-pc2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PC2DOK/pages/1903406/VPN) to setup VPN connection. I built OpenVPN version 2.6.8 (most up-to-date) from source and `make check` command shows it passes test running. I got the network certificate from the institute and recorded the import password.
I ran

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Network_Certificate.p12 -noout -password pass:[the recorded import password]
```

to test the import password. There is no `Mac verify error: invalid password?` message, which means the import password I recorded is working. Then I ran

```
sudo openvpn OpenVPN-UPB-NG_hpc-pc2_lin.ovpn
```

as instructed and input the import password carefully to make sure it is correct. But I still received a lot of errors, one of which is

```
Error: private key password verification failed
```

Do you know where the problem is and how to fix it so that I can set up the VPN successfully? Thanks.

Some information for troubleshooting:

- I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 server.
- The output of `openssl pkcs12 -in Network_Certificate.p12 -noout -password pass:[the recorded import password]`:

[image]

- The output of `sudo openvpn OpenVPN-UPB-NG_hpc-pc2_lin.ovpn`:

[image]